# Invoke Parallel Process from WebService in Java

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, servlets, parallel-processing

I have devoloped a WebService (WS1) in Java which is deployed in a Tomcat Server. 
If certain conditions are met, WS1 needs to invoke another WebService (WS2) to run in parallel. Is this possible? or does the WS1 has to wait for the response of WS2 to keep running. The point of this is not delaying the response of WS1 as it is not dependant of WS2. However, WS2 trigger IS dependant of WS1 and that's how my problem starts.

My hipothetical solution to this issue is to create a separate servlet which invokes WS2 without delaying WS1. How can I implement it or can anyone think of a better solution?

Comment: Yes its doable -- http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/09/19/asynchronous-jax-ws-web-services.html

Comment: do you really mean a seperate web service, or a background process? Could you describe what you would like to do?

Comment: If the conditions are met, WS1 needs to retrieve data from the database and call another web service which is located in another Server and with the response, it needs to update some information in our database. In other words, it needs to run a background process and call a separate web service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you want to achieve. If you just want to kickoff the second WS, you could create a new local thread and do the call. The second WS might even support asynchronous calls so that you are not blocked after calling it. Creating a new thread would work as follows.

First, you need a class for this thread. This class would take care of communicating with WS2:

```
class ThreadForWS2 extends Thread {
  public void run() {
    // invoke WS2 here
  }
}
```

In your WS1 request handler, you just need to kick-off this thread, e.g.:

```
Thread threadForWS2 = new ThreadForWS2();
threadForWS2.start();
```

That's it, but of course there are many ways in Java to create another thread. That's up to you to investigate the best possible solution.

Comment: Calling `Thread.run()` does not actually start a new thread, but instead runs the code in the *current* thread. To start the new thread, you need to call `Thread.start()` (so `threadForWS2.start()`).

Comment: @JonathanCallen Yes, you are absolutely right. That's what happens if you program without testing :-/ I updated my answer.

Comment: @Sebi is it necessary to stop/kill the thread? the thing is, the process that invokes the thread dies before the thread would finish, is this an issue?

Comment: @user1084509 If the response of WS1 depends on the data that WS2 returns, then you cannot call WS2 asynchronously.  You would have to wait for the WS2 response in order to incorporate it into the WS1 response.

Comment: @Michael the response of WS1 does not depend on the data that WS2 returns.

Comment: @user1084509 Ok, in that case, you **can** call WS2 asynchronously.  About terminating the thread, you don't have to do anything to explicitly terminate it.  It will automatically terminate when it finishes executing the `run()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it can be done. 
I would like to know if you're tallking about SOAP or RESTFul web service 
In general in both technologies, you can have a method invoked in WS1, that as a result, communicates with WS2 (i.e - sends HTTP request with REST data to a resource URL or send a SOAP envelope) 
If you mean by running in parallel to open a thread an execute the invocation code of the method in WS2 - this is possible as well 
In addition, from what I saw servlet API 3.0 supports asynchronous calls, maybe this can help you as well

Answer (score 0):

You would have to invoke WS2 in an **asynchronous** manor.  This means that the web service call is handled in a separate thread and does not impact the execution of the parent thread (WS1).

The opposite of an asynchronous call is a **synchronous** call, which blocks the current thread until a response is received.

Comment: Relying on an asynchronous call was also the first solution I had in mind. However, it might be that WS2 has no asynchronous interface and that the poster has no chance to add one. In that case, you need to call WS2 from another thread to not block execution of WS1.

Comment: Yeah, how the asynchronous call is actually made depends on the framework that the OP is using (if any).

Comment: ...and on the second web service. If it doesn't support asynchronous request, there is no chance to do one...

Comment: @Sebi There's no such thing as a web service "supporting" asynchronous calls or not.  When you say that you are calling a web service "asynchronously", it just means that you spawn a new thread and invoke the web service in that thread.

Comment: That's a bit weird definition I would say. At least W3C WebServices (SOAP, WSDL, etc.) explicitly distinguish between a synchronous and asynchronous interface. If you make a request to a synchronous interface, your code will be blocked till the response was received. Of course you can work around that by putting the call in a new thread, but this doesn't change the behaviour of the web service.

Comment: @Sebi Well I would say that the W3C's definition is a bit weird.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but I don't understand how a web service can be labeled as "synchronous" or "asynchronous".  To me, these terms have to do with the way in which the web service is called **on the client**, so it's a **client-side** issue, not a server-side issue.  In other words, it has nothing to do with how the web service is implemented on the server-side.

Comment: Not the web service is asynchronous or synchronous, but it may only provide a synchronous interface. No matter what you do, if you call this interface, your client thread calling the interface will be blocked till a response returns.

Comment: @Sebi But again that's a client-side implementation issue isn't it?  The interface that you choose to use to invoke the web service is all client-side programming.  At a lower level, when you invoke a web service, what you are doing is sending an HTTP request and waiting for an HTTP response.  The **client** can **choose** to (1) send the HTTP request in the same thread and wait for the response, thus blocking the thread or (2) send the HTTP request in a separate thread and continue executing the current thread.

Comment: Sure, you can always misuse a standard. But if you call a synchronous interface of a W3C web service, it is expected that you wait till you received the response. That's how the standard is defined. See 1.2.1: http://java.sun.com/blueprints/webservices/using/webservbp3.html

Comment: @Sebi Oh I see.  An asynchronous service, as described in the article, is a type of service that is used for when it takes a long time to process the request.  Upon accepting a request, the web service immediately returns a response to the client.  The response contains an ID, which the client uses to poll the web service to check to see if it's done processing the request or not.  Also,  instead of polling, the client can be configured to accept a pushed message from the server which contains the result of the request.